# Android DownloadManager get filename

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager, receiver

In my app you can download some files. I used the Android `DownloadManager` class for downloading. After the download is completed, it should show me a message that the file was downloaded. The problem is, there could be 2,3 or 4 downloads at the same time. My `BroadcastReceiver` code looks like this:

```
receiver_complete = new BroadcastReceiver(){
         @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) ){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.download_finished, "Here should be the name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
         }
     };
```

How can I get the current filename of the finished download?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you want to put something like this inside your `if` block.  Replace `YOUR_DM` with your DownloadManager instance.

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
q.setFilterById(extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID));
Cursor c = YOUR_DM.query(q);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
        // process download
        title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
        // get other required data by changing the constant passed to getColumnIndex
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this code inside a BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 22):

Ian Shannon was totally right with his answer, but I sugest some improvement:

- Remember to close that `Cursor` after using it, avoiding "Cursor Leaking". This `Cursor` consumes a lot of resources and must be released as soon as possible.
- If you put some title for the download, such as:

  ```
  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
  request.setTitle("Some title");
  ```

  The value given by the `DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE` will be `"Some title"` instead of the file name. So I would recommend this instead:

  ```
  String filePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
  title = filePath.substring( filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filePath.length() );
  ```

  The `COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME` returns the entire path (`/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/.../filename.ext`), but with this code, we will only get the file name.

Final code:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
q.setFilterById(extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID));
Cursor c = YOUR_DM.query(q);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
        String filePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
        filename = filePath.substring( filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filePath.length() );
    }
}
c.close();
```

**Edit:** Replace YOUR_DM with your DownloadManager instance.

Comment: Beware that `COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME` is **deprecated**. You can get an `Uri` using `COLUMN_LOCAL_URI` which is the Uri of the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE`

Here is a link to the Android Documents: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#COLUMN_TITLE

And here is a tutorial that will explain more than just getting the title. It is for downloading an image from a URL and then displaying it in an application. Mighty useful I think, overall speaking.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/downloading-an-image-from-an-http-url-using-downloadmanager-and-displaying-in-imageview-by-dynamically-registered-broadcastreceiver/

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to retrieve the downloaded file URI, and that is with `getUriForDownloadedFile`:

```
download_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        long file_id = b.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID);
        Uri uri = dm.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloaded_file_id);

    }
}
```

I found this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31275425/4562156) in a full description of how to use a BroadcastReceiver for handling DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE events.

Answer (score 0):

## Actualy in 2023

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
```

which is not found from url parsing but received from

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myDocument.FileName"
```

Answer (score -1):

u try this code to get the file name

DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME

i am not sure about it