# How to play My video once downloaded?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have managed to download my video on the device, but cannot access it again to play it on my app. I am using the generated uri to reference my video back to the videoView, but the uri generated at

uri= downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(reference); is null according my my log message.

What am I doing wrong?

public void saveLocal(View v){

```
    downloadManager= (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    String url= "http://adme360.otscom.net/tim10.mp4";
    uris= Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request= new DownloadManager.Request(uris);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    Long reference=downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    Toast.makeText(this,""+reference,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);



    uri= downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(reference);

    Log.d("REFERENCE", ""+uri);
}
public void playLocal(View v){
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();

}
```

Comment: you have to use Brocast receiver

Comment: Check here complete referece : https://github.com/anugotta/DownloadManagerExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gadgetsaint/downloadmanagerexample/MainActivity.java

Comment: http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/download-manager/#.WnyYDnVuY3U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download is down asynchronously. The video is downloaded on an other thread. You need to register a broadcast receiver to get the callback when your download is completed. [Quoting from answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477493/android-download-manager-completed)

> A Broadcast intent action sent by the download manager when a download completes so you need to register a receiver for when the download is complete:
>
> To register receiver

```
registerReceiver(onComplete, newIntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

> and a BroadcastReciever handler

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    // your code
    }
};`
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense but is not working for me. What I am trying to do is download the file, find its unique Long reference, and then try and play the video by using the find Uri. My Uri value is returning null. I want to know why, because my download is very successful.

Comment: you need to write that code in onReceive of broadcaseReciever

Comment: Yeah. I tried it out. It works. Your right, the video download occurs in a separate thread.