# After download a document download manager keep showing toast "Download Failed" even though it successfull

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-download-manager, download-manager

I create a download manager for downloading a document but it always shows the toast `download failed`. Even if I haven't set the toast for download complete, it still exists and the document that I download was successfully downloaded.

Here is my code:

```
class ShareDokumenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var tempDatas: ArrayList<ListWa>? = null

var list: ArrayList<Long> = ArrayList()
private var mgr: DownloadManager? = null
private val MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 100
var filename = ""
var fileUrl = ""
var ext = ""
var type =""
var newNumbCode =""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_wa)
    titleSearch.setText("Share file to...")
    titleSearch.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

    val savedUser = Gson().fromJson<LoginUser>(this@ShareDokumenActivity
            .getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.MY_LOGIN_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString(LoginActivity.MY_LOGIN_PREF_KEY, ""), LoginUser::class.java)
    getListWa(savedUser.salesmanId)
    chooseShareTo()

}

fun getListWa(id : String){
    API.getListWa(id).enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<ListWa>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<ListWa>>, response: Response<ArrayList<ListWa>>) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                tempDatas = response.body();
                rvListWa.setHasFixedSize(true)
                rvListWa.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ShareDokumenActivity)
                rvListWa.adapter = ListWaAdapter(tempDatas)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@ShareDokumenActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<ListWa>>, throwable: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ShareDokumenActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })

}

fun chooseShareTo(){
    rvListWa!!.addOnItemTouchListener(RecyclerItemClickListener(this@ShareDokumenActivity,
            RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener { view, position ->

                val numbCode = tempDatas!![position].custHpWa
                if (numbCode.substring(0,2).equals("08")){
                    newNumbCode = "62"+numbCode.substring(1)

                    fileUrl = baseURLPicasso + intent.getStringExtra(SalesProgramDocViewersActivity.DOC_URL_INTENT)
                    val mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                    ext = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
                    type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext)

                    filename = intent.getStringExtra(SalesProgramDocViewersActivity.DOC_URL_INTENT).substring(44)
                    val downloadUri = Uri.parse(fileUrl)
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@ShareDokumenActivity,
                                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@ShareDokumenActivity,
                                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE)
                    } else {
                        mgr?.enqueue(DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri)
                                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                                .setTitle("Downloading..")
                                .setDescription("Download " + filename)
                                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename))
                    }


                }else if (numbCode.substring(0,2).equals("+6")){
                    newNumbCode = numbCode.substring(1)
                    Toast.makeText(this@ShareDokumenActivity, "$newNumbCode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this@ShareDokumenActivity, "Kode nomor salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }))
}

fun sendFile(filename: String, extension : String, phoneNumb : String) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@ShareDokumenActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@ShareDokumenActivity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE)
    } else {
        val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + filename)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@ShareDokumenActivity, this@ShareDokumenActivity.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", dir)
            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, extension)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
            intent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(phoneNumb) + "@s.whatsapp.net")

        } else {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(dir), extension)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(dir))
            intent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(phoneNumb) + "@s.whatsapp.net")
        }

        try {
            this@ShareDokumenActivity.startActivity(intent)
//            Toast.makeText(this@ShareDokumenActivity, "Download Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this@ShareDokumenActivity, "Can't sharing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mgr = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager?
    registerReceiver(onComplete, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
}

var onComplete : BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(ctxt: Context, intent: Intent) {
        sendFile(filename, type, newNumbCode)
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it is successful ?

Comment: yes, i have check it in my file manager.

Comment: cross check the file size too. I suspect it might be failing somewhere

Comment: yeah i try to download with a different size too. both are successful but the toast still failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477493/android-download-manager-completed. Try adding the download complete listener from the link and see if it is triggered or not

Comment: i have the one with the complete listener. I'll edit my code

Comment: check my update code