# Android Download Manager response message

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download a file using `DownloadManager`, but I have a few scenarios to make decision on download response.

How to get success response message from download manager?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21477493/7746134

Comment: Hi Sir, i checked this link. but am not able to get response message.

Comment: Please show some codes to further help you

Comment: am using same code of above link.