# downloaded image not showing in galllery android

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager, android-external-storage

I am trying to download an image from the URL and save it in android. but I am facing one problem here downloaded images are not showing in the gallery. I tried previously asked questions on stack overflow they didn't work for me.
here is my code:
API version is 30.
please any help will be appreciated Thanks.

```
package com.example.testscripts;
/imports/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        Button clickbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        clickbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText ein = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urltext);
                Content content = new Content();
                content.execute(String.valueOf(ein.getText()));
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void downloadFile(String imgurls) throws IOException {
        String imageURL = imgurls;
        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(imgurls);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
                .setDescription("someting")
                .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "hello.jpg");
        mgr.enqueue(request);
        File fles = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"hello.jpg");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse(fles.getAbsolutePath())));
    }

    private class Content extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>  {
        private String val1;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
            try {
                val1 = (String) voids[0];
                String urls = val1;
                downloadFile(urls);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have updated my question this is my full source code beside imports.

Comment: was the picture saved? can you see it in the folder?

Comment: `direct.mkdirs();` Check the return value of mkdirs and dont continue if it fails. Instead display a toast to inform the user and return.

Comment: You are messing around with getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: @Felix yes image is saved in folder i can see it file manager

Comment: I use the MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(), look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814533/13727175), it works fine for me.

Comment: @blackapps what is sir? can explain me please ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that you are calling the media scanner exactly after enqueuing the download request. Since the image is not downloaded yet, you should register a `BroadcastReceiver` to know when the download gets finished, then run the media scanner.

See this: [Android download manager completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477493/android-download-manager-completed)

---

#### Edit:

If the target api level is `29`, notice that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated and not to be used. ([Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()))

Comment: I tried this still no luck..even I tried to call it on `onClick` still no update

Comment: Please share an example of file path and its uri string.

Comment: hi sorry for the late response, I have updated the code with my full source code