# Using Android DownloadManager,how do i get file name?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using DownloadManager class to manage downloads, i'm using this

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,subPath);
```

currently i'm setting subPath to some filename but how do i get filename from url?

I don't want to use cursor but some way to extract file name from uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE
```

Please look at [Android DownloadManager get filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321984/android-downloadmanager-get-filename)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well , if no cursor then try this:

```
class GetFileName extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    URL url;
    String filename = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urls[0]);
        String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        con.connect();

        String content = con.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        String contentSplit[] = content.split("filename=");
        filename = contentSplit[1].replace("filename=", "").replace("\"", "").trim();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return filename;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

}
}
```